# Why doesn't Javascript perform two operations simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, frontend, dom-events

Why doesn't Javascript perform two operations simultaneously? i.e. row delete and row insert.

```
var tookSum= false;

function alterTable()
{ 
    
    //Textboxes code
    
    var tBoxCompany= document.getElementById("txtboxCompany");
    var tBoxAmount= document.getElementById("txtboxAmount");
    
     
    
    //table code
    
    var table= document.getElementById("tableNetWorths");
    
    var rowCount= table.rows.length;
    
    if(tookSum == true)
    {
        table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);
        tookSum= false;
    }
    
    var row= table.insertRow(rowCount);
    
    var Cell1= row.insertCell(0);
    var Cell2= row.insertCell(1);
    
    Cell1.innerHTML= tBoxCompany.value;
    Cell2.innerHTML= tBoxAmount.value;
  
}
```

The above-given function is executed upon button click. It works but I have to press button twice i.e. first to delete row and then add a new row but I want it to 'delete and add' in single a click.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the problem you are presenting?

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all. `tookSum == true` is always `false`. JavaScript doesn't delete the row because you are telling it to only delete it if `tookSum` is `true`. But you are initializing it with `false` and are never changing it to `true`. I.e. you are telling it to never the delete the row.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do, Check if `rowCount > 0` before deleting row from table

**Try this:**

```
if(rowCount > 0)
{
    table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);
}
```

In the earlier answer, if there is no row exist in table then `table.deleteRow(rowCount-1)` will not work, so check row count to confirm there is a row available in table to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this:

```
if(tookSum == true)
{
    table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);
    tookSum= false;
}
```

with this:

```
table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);
```

Despite the fact that **this is not clear to your code**, the value of `tookSum` *should be* true at the first click. Hence at the first click a row is deleted and the `tookSum` value is updated to false. So the second time you click none row would be deleted and a new row would be inserted. I did this assumption based on that you claim is true, you need to clicks and function `alterTable` is executed when you click at the button you mentioned.